# How to bypass the Spring @PreAuthorize annotation on RestController for tests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, pcfdev

How can I create a bypass **@Preauthorize** so that I can test in local with out calling the actual because annotation will be loaded before the class loads ?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class ResourceController {
    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    @PreAuthorize
    @ResponseBody
    public String message(){ return "Hello World"; }
```

Comment: just to point you to alternative, did you know you could use `@MockUser` in your tests? see [Testing Method Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spring-security-test` to achieve this.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Supposedly your controller looks like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
  public User createUser(final User user) {
    ......
  }
```

And your test can look like:

```
public class MyControllerTests {

  private MockMvc mvc;
  
  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
        .webAppContextSetup(context)
        .apply(springSecurity())
        .build();
  }

  @Test
  void testCreateWithProperPermission() throws Exception {
    
    final User user = new User();
    user.setName("Test");

    final MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/v1/foo/").with(user("foo").roles("ADMIN"))
        .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        
    final String responseBody = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

    final User created = new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseBody, User.class);

    // verify the saved entity's data is correct
    assertThat(created).isNotNull();
    assertThat(created)
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("name", user.getName());

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a test profile in your code which you then activate when running tests against the code. You can then use the predefined user and password in your tests.

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

  @EnableWebSecurity
  @Profile("test")
  class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
      InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
      manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("password").roles("ROLE1", "ROLE2", "ROLE3").build());
      return manager;
    }
  }
}
```